# If the price of an article is increased by percent $p$....

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the price of an article is increased by percent $p$, then the decrease in percent of sales must not exceed $d$ in order to yield the same income. The value of $d$ is:
$\textbf{(A)}\ \frac{1}{1+p} \qquad \textbf{(B)}\ \frac{1}{1-p} \qquad \textbf{(C)}\ \frac{p}{1+p} \qquad \textbf{(D)}\ \frac{p}{p-1}\qquad \textbf{(E)}\ \frac{1-p}{1+p}$

My try  :

Suppose that original price=$x$ , then price  after increase =$x+px =x (1+p)$

Sales before  increase = $x.n$

Sales after increase =$ x.n. (1+p)$

For the sales to be equal $ \to $

$x.n=x.n. (1+p).d \to d=\frac {1}{p+1}$

Comment: What is your question, whether you solved correctly this elementary school problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neutralizing the effects of the increase and the decrease,

$$(1+p)(1-q)=1,$$ so that

$$q=1-\frac1{1+p}=\frac p{1+p}.$$

---

By the geometric progression formula, we can also write

$$q=p(1-p+p^2-p^3-\cdots)\approx p-p^2.$$

Comment: can you elaborate  the first  equation  a bit  more  please , i didn't get it

Comment: $xn(1+p)(1-q)=xn$ if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Your last line is wrong.

$$x\cdot n=x\cdot n (1+p)\color{red}{(1-d)}$$

Because $d$ is percentage in decrease of sale, not the fraction by which sale is decreased.